# Starting apps from notifications in freeform mode

Tags: kotlin, notifications, android-launcher

I'm implementing the launcher in kotlin. When the user clicks on the status bar notification i want the app associated with the notification to be run in freeform mode. Currently when the user clicks on the notification the app launches in fullscreen mode, I've implemented that by getting notificaitionIntent from the sbn and calling send() function on it:
`val notificationIntent = sbn.notification.contentIntent`

I've had an idea of extracting the Intent from the PendingIntent so i could add the options for freeform mode, but from what i've read that's impossible, and since i can't add anything directly to the pending intent how can i make this work?